# How do I implement a routine to convert epoch timestamp without using any library/package?

Tags: java, algorithm, datetime, epoch

I am implementing a routine to convert from Epoch timestamp into year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds.

**Important note: I can not use any of the existing Java libraries because this routine is used as a test program to be later implemented in a GPU. Therefore please do not suggest to use Localdate, ZonedDateTime, Datetime, etc. The routine must use plain data types and basic arithmetic operations.**

These are the specs:

1. The input data is a `UNIX Epoch timestamp in seconds`.
2. The output data is a string with the `year/month/day hour:minute`.
3. The date times are constrained from `January 1st 1990` to `January 1st 2050`.
4. `No leap seconds` as input data are UNIX Epoch timestamps.

Only valid epoch timestamps based on these conditions are handled by the routine.

This is what I have tried, which I include as a replicable Java program.

I have a valid routine which works for dates above January 1st 2000: routine `epochToDatetimeBase2000`.

I am trying to code a module which will work for dates above January 1st 1990, routine `epochToDatetimeBase1990`, which does not work.

This is the complete replicable source code of the program including both routines and the test data:

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static String epochToDatetimeBase2000(int epoch) {

        int epochOriginal = epoch;

        epoch = epoch - 946684800;      //  946684800 is Epoch for Saturday, 1 January 2000 00:00:00

        int[] days = new int[]{
            0,  31,  60,  91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335,
            366, 397, 425, 456, 486, 517, 547, 578, 609, 639, 670, 700,
            731, 762, 790, 821, 851, 882, 912, 943, 974,1004,1035,1065,
            1096,1127,1155,1186,1216,1247,1277,1308,1339,1369,1400,1430
        };        

        int second = epoch % 60;
        epoch = epoch / 60;
        int minute = epoch % 60;
        epoch = epoch / 60;
        int hour   = epoch % 24;
        epoch = epoch / 24;

        int years = epoch/(365*4+1)*4; 
        epoch %= 365*4+1;

        int year;
        for (year=3; year>0; year=year-1)
        {   
            if (epoch >= days[year*12])
                break;
        }

        int month;
        for (month=11; month>0; month--)
        {
            if (epoch >= days[year*12 + month])
                break;
        }

        int yearVal = years+year;
        int monthVal = month+1;
        int dayVal = epoch-days[year*12 + month]+1;

        String strDatetime = String.format("%d %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d.%02d", epochOriginal, dayVal, monthVal, 2000+yearVal, hour, minute, second); // Float value.

        return strDatetime;

    }

    public static String epochToDatetimeBase1990(int epoch) {

        int epochOriginal = epoch;

        epoch = epoch - 631152000;      // 631152000 is Epoch for Monday, 1 January 1990 00:00:00

        int[] days = new int[]{
            0,  31,  60,  91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335,
            366, 397, 425, 456, 486, 517, 547, 578, 609, 639, 670, 700,
            731, 762, 790, 821, 851, 882, 912, 943, 974,1004,1035,1065,
            1096,1127,1155,1186,1216,1247,1277,1308,1339,1369,1400,1430
        };        

        int second = epoch % 60;
        epoch = epoch / 60;
        int minute = epoch % 60;
        epoch = epoch / 60;
        int hour   = epoch % 24;
        epoch = epoch / 24;

        int years = epoch/(365*4+1)*4; 
        epoch %= 365*4+1;

        int year;
        for (year=3; year>0; year=year-1)
        {   
            if (epoch >= days[year*12])
                break;
        }

        int month;
        for (month=11; month>0; month--)
        {
            if (epoch >= days[year*12 + month])
                break;
        }

        int yearVal = years+year;
        int monthVal = month+1;
        int dayVal = epoch-days[year*12 + month]+1;

        String strDatetime = String.format("%d %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d.%02d", epochOriginal, dayVal, monthVal, 1990+yearVal, hour, minute, second); // Float value.

        return strDatetime;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // USING BASE 2000
        System.out.println(epochToDatetimeBase2000(978307200));     // Epoch timestamp: 978307200       Date and time (GMT): Monday, 1 January 2001 00:00:00
        System.out.println(epochToDatetimeBase2000(631152000));     // Epoch timestamp: 631152000       Date and time (GMT): Tuesday, 1 January 1990 00:00:00
        System.out.println(epochToDatetimeBase2000(662688000));     // Epoch timestamp: 662688000       Date and time (GMT): Tuesday, 1 January 1991 00:00:00

        // USING BASE 1990
        System.out.println(epochToDatetimeBase1990(978307200));     // Epoch timestamp: 978307200       Date and time (GMT): Monday, 1 January 2001 00:00:00
        System.out.println(epochToDatetimeBase1990(631152000));     // Epoch timestamp: 631152000       Date and time (GMT): Tuesday, 1 January 1990 00:00:00
        System.out.println(epochToDatetimeBase1990(662688000));     // Epoch timestamp: 662688000       Date and time (GMT): Tuesday, 1 January 1991 00:00:00


    }


}
```

This is the output:

```
978307200 01/01/2001 00:00.00
631152000 -729/01/1992 00:00.00
662688000 -364/01/1992 00:00.00

978307200 01/01/2001 00:00.00
631152000 01/01/1990 00:00.00
662688000 31/12/1990 00:00.00     <- SHALL BE  1 January 1991 00:00:00
```

Comment: look at your output `631152000 -729/01/1992 00:00.00` perhaps the negative number is not ok either?

Comment: In that case the negative number can be expected because that is the original routine that I converted from C ( https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125275/converting-the-datetime-to-and-from-unix-epoch-times) which handled only timestamps from year 2000. So the input data for that routine is actually beyond the specs. What I am trying to do is to rewrite that routine `epochToDatetimeBase2000`so it can handle timestamps from year 1990 to 2050. `epochToDatetimeBase1990` is what I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could there be a mistake in your `days` array for `epochToDatetimeBase1990`? I notice the values are exactly the same as in `epochToDatetimeBase2000`. 2000 is leap year but 1990 **isn't**! So the leap years begin in different places in the array. I think `days` should defined like be this in `epochToDatetimeBase1990`:

```java
int[] days = new int[]{
    // 1990 is NOT a leap year
    0,  31,  59,  90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334,
    365, 396, 424, 455, 485, 516, 546, 577, 608, 638, 669, 699,

    // 1992 is a leap year here
    730, 761, 790, 821, 851, 882, 912, 943, 974,1004,1035,1065,
    1096,1127,1155,1186,1216,1247,1277,1308,1339,1369,1400,1430
};
```

Comment: I am sure that the issue is located there as you mention Klarth, I am still struggling to understand what exactly that array represents. I will try with your arrange but still would like to understand how this array is constructed.

Comment: Its the accumulative number of days. The first (`days[0]`) is 0, the first day of the year. For the rest, its `days[i] = days[i-1] + (number of days in month)`. The entry at index 1 represents January with 31 days. Take that and add it to the previous entry (0). This gives 31 for `days[1]`. `days[2]` is February, with 28 days in a non-leap year. Take that and add to `days[1]` for a value of 59. `days[3]` is March with 31 days, `days[3] = days[2] + 31` or 90, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now it makes sense. I will throughly test your rearrangement.

Comment: Thanks it is perfectly clear and it works fine now. As side information related to leap years in case it might help others:   https://kalender-365.de/leap-years.php   and   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-a-leap-year

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared another solution. Please have a look.

Also this is helpful for any other boundary of years, for that just change START_YEAR, START_EPOCH and END_YEAR.

```
final static int START_YEAR = 1990;
final static long START_EPOCH = 631152000;
final static int END_YEAR = 2050;
final static int[] MONTH_DAYS = new int[]{31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

private static void convertEpochToDateTime(long epoch){
    long relativeEpoch = epoch-START_EPOCH;

    int[] daysAndRemainingSeconds = getTotalDaysAndRemainingSeconds(relativeEpoch);
    int remainingSeconds = daysAndRemainingSeconds[1];
    int[] time = convertSecondsToTime(remainingSeconds);

    int totalDays = daysAndRemainingSeconds[0];
    int[] yearAndRemainingDays = getYearAndRemainingDays(totalDays);
    int year = yearAndRemainingDays[0];
    int remainingDays = yearAndRemainingDays[1];

    int[] monthAndDays =getMonthsAndRemaingDays(remainingDays,isLeapYear(year));

    String strDatetime = String.format("%d %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d.%02d", epoch, monthAndDays[1]+1, monthAndDays[0], year, time[0], time[1], time[2]);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(strDatetime));
}

private static int[] getTotalDaysAndRemainingSeconds(long seconds){
    return new int[]{(int)seconds/86400,(int)seconds%86400};
}

private static int[] getYearAndRemainingDays(int days){
    int tmpDays = 0;
    for(int year=START_YEAR;year<=END_YEAR;year++){
        int daysInYear = isLeapYear(year)?366:365;
        if(tmpDays+daysInYear>days) return new int[]{year,days-tmpDays};
        tmpDays +=daysInYear;
    }
    return new int[]{0,0};
}

private static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
    return ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
}

private static int[] convertSecondsToTime(int seconds){
    int sec = seconds % 60;
    int hr = seconds / 60;
    int min = hr % 60;
    hr = hr / 60;
    return new int[]{hr,min,sec};
}

private static int[] getMonthsAndRemaingDays(int days,boolean leapYear){
    int tmdDays = 0;
    for(int month=1;month<=12;month++){
        int daysInThisMonth = MONTH_DAYS[month-1]+(month==2 && leapYear?1:0);
        if(tmdDays+daysInThisMonth>days) return new int[]{month,days-tmdDays};
        tmdDays+=daysInThisMonth;
    }
    return new int[]{12,0};
}
```